# After using `networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi "8.8.8.8" "8.8.4.4"` how do I clear them?

Tags: macos, network, command-line, dns

I'm looking to script a temporary DNS server change to override the DHCP response I get from the network. I've figured out I can use `networksetup` but once we're done testing. Before I push to production, I figure I should know how to undo this.

How can I script to clear these changes and restore the settings the network provides now as if I never ran the following script?

```
networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi "8.8.8.8" "8.8.4.4"
```

It's not feasible to save any the previous settings and I'm looking to remove the setting so that the actual new values can be retrieved from the network as opposed to saving what the settings were previously so I don't save an old value that is no longer correct.

Basically, I'm looking to `ipconfig /renew` on macOS.

Comment: I came here looking for a way to set the DNS servers back to the default. For the record, the thing I was looking for is spelled [`networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi Empty`](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7375118).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're concerned only about cleaning DNS entries, the  command help gives you instructions what to do:

```
Usage: networksetup -setdnsservers <networkservice> <dns1> [dns2] [...]
       Set the <networkservice> DNS servers to <dns1> [dns2] [...]. Any 
       number of dns servers can be specified. Specify "Empty" for <dns1> 
       to clear all DNS entries.
```

In my case

```
sudo networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi "Empty"
```

Answer (score 3):

- Create a new network service with the respective interface (e.g. en1 = AirPort):

  `sudo networksetup -createnetworkservice Wi-Fi2 en1`
- Remove the one with the custom DNS settings:

  `sudo networksetup -removenetworkservice Wi-Fi`
- Rename the new network service to the original name:

  `sudo networksetup -renamenetworkservice Wi-Fi2 Wi-Fi`

In my environment the new service fetched DHCP and its new settings automatically. You may have to set it with `sudo networksetup -setdhcp Wi-Fi` explicitly or look at the DHCP response for the interface and parse the supplied DNS ip(s) with `ipconfig getpacket en1` though.

Comment: Now that’s elegant - no need to remove a setting if the interface can be disposable. Next steps is I will have to test if this is reliable when we script this remotely, but it’s probably no more dangerous than my “test” settings.

Comment: I came up with this little bash alias based on this answer:

alias bouncewifi="sudo networksetup -createnetworkservice Wi-Fi2 $(networksetup -listallhardwareports|grep -A1 Wi-Fi|fgrep Device|awk '{print $2}') && sudo networksetup -removenetworkservice Wi-Fi && sudo networksetup -renamenetworkservice Wi-Fi2 Wi-Fi"

Since my Wi-Fi is usually en0 and not en1, I used network setup to find out which device the current Wi-Fi was on and then executed the 3 above commands in order based on exit conditions of the previous command. This should be fairly safe to do remotely.

Comment: IMHO, creating a new network service every time to do this can have a lot of side effects.  Like I think the new interface will have to re-negotiate DHCP each time?  It's also just very usual so I fear other intended side effects.

For temporarily changing DNS settings and then restoring them, I put together a little zsh/bash script that does that here: https://gist.github.com/varenc/388fa10c68002e0d59c67d1b52492f79

Setting a sleeping background job the restore DNS after a certain amount of time, and check for duplicates and kills them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to **System Preferences** and follow the steps in my screenshots.

**step 1:**
[image]

**step 2:**
[image]

sorry for german screenshots.

once you removed all manually configured nameservers, Mac OS will use nameservers provided by DHCP again.

Comment: this question is about scripting, so fixing manually via the UI doesn't really help.  Though it is good to know.  Just using the magical  `networksetup -setdnsservers NetServiceName "Empty"` is the right cli solution.