# Remove custom dns server setting via command line

Tags: network, dns

So I typically run the following to set a custom DNS server when I am on WiFi:

```
networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi <desired-dns-server-here>
```

However, I would like to know how to unset custom DNS servers and revert to DHCP provided DNS. [This](http://osxdaily.com/2015/06/02/change-dns-command-line-mac-os-x/) article from 2015 says that running `networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi` should do this, but on macOS 10.15 that results in `** Error: The amount of parameters was not correct.`

Any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a one liner and the thread where I learned this a while back:

```
sudo networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi "Empty"
```

[After using `networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi "8.8.8.8" "8.8.4.4"` how do I clear them?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/288960/)

Comment: Been looking for this command for sometime. For some reason VPN works slightly better when explicitly defining the DNS servers (on mac) but didnt know how to revert it back to clear (empty). I created alias for these. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `man networksetup`

```
-getdnsservers networkservice
         Displays DNS info for <networkservice>.

 -setdnsservers networkservice dns1 [dns2] [...]
         Use this command to specify the IP addresses of servers you want the specified <networkser-
         vice> to use to resolve domain names. You can list any number of servers (replace dns1, dns2,
         and so on with the IP addresses of domain name servers). If you want to clear all DNS entries
         for the specified network service, type "empty" in place of the DNS server names.
```

You can list all dns using the first command, copy them or simply use pipelining to clipboard using `pbcopy` as follows:

`networksetup -getdnsservers Wi-Fi | pbcopy`

Them `empty` the list, and add back the desired.

Comment: So close with the “empty” missing - sub that in for piping to pbcopy. I didn’t see your post till I was done writing mine.

Comment: I assumed that OP had a list of say 5 entries and they wanted to remove 2 of them. So first get - pbcopy - set empty - set the required.